# Jquery code to show loading before display the main content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working with `jquery` on my page, I want when ever user click on a button an image will show loading for 1 second before the main content appears

Here is my code:

```
      <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#UseractivityLog").click(function(){
          $(".UserProfileLogs-cont").html("<img src='image/loading.gif'/>");
//Then for 1/2 seconds this UserProfileLogs will display
          $(".UserProfileLogs").toggle();
      });  
          $("#IdealLog").click(function(){
          $(".UserProfileLogs-con").toggle();
      });  
      });
      </script>
```

Here is my HTML part

```
<a href="#" id="UseractivityLog">Logs</a>
<div id="UserProfileLogs-cont">
<div id="IdealLog"></div>
<div id="UserProfileLogs"></div>
</div>
```

Please i will appreciate jsfiled sample

Comment: Use can use setTimeout().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` to update the image source after `n` seconds.

Also you can achieve this using single `div` and an nested `img` without using separate container for loading icon and image.

Hope this below snippet will be useful

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="UseractivityLog">Logs</a>
<div id="UserProfileLogs-cont">
  <img src="">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var _gif = "http://assets.motherjones.com/interactives/projects/features/koch-network/shell19/img/loading.gif";
var _forest="http://www.discovertheforest.org/images/hero/home/6.jpg";
          $("#UseractivityLog").click(function(){
          $("#UserProfileLogs-cont img").attr("src",_gif);
          setTimeout(function(){
          $("#UserProfileLogs-cont img").attr("src",_forest);
          },3000)
        });  

      });
```

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uav84eaL/)

Comment: I tried loading another page but i kept loading image `var _forest = "<?php echo slash;?>php-inc/Profilelogs.php";`

Comment: what is another page?

Answer (score 1):

You have some selector inconstancies, make sure you are watching those (`#` instead of `.`).

For the pause, use `setTimout()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#UseractivityLog").click(function(){
        $("#UserProfileLogs-cont").html("Loading...");
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#UserProfileLogs-cont").html("<img src='http://placehold.it/350x150'>");
        }, 1000);

        //Then for 1/2 seconds this UserProfileLogs will display
        $(".UserProfileLogs").toggle();
    });  
    $("#IdealLog").click(function(){
        $("#UserProfileLogs-cont").toggle();
    });  
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lqgum8hu/

For your comment:

> //Then for 1/2 seconds this UserProfileLogs will display

Use another timeout:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // Whatever...
}, 500);
```

I changed your HTML a little to present the examples, but it can be changed to however you want it without changing the Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can wait until the body is ready:

```
function onReady(callback) {
    var intervalID = window.setInterval(checkReady, 1000);
    function checkReady() {
        if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] !== undefined) {
            window.clearInterval(intervalID);
            callback.call(this);
        }
    }
}

function show(id, value) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = value ? 'block' : 'none';
}

onReady(function () {
    show('page', true);
    show('loading', false);
});


#page {
    display: none;
}
#loading {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.5);
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnyxU.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle that demonstrates this technique.

Comment: i really don't know how to use the code can you give me example with my post